# How to combine dataframes based on the names in common in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

So my data is currently split into 211 dataframes in R and I was wondering if there was a way to combine all of them without having to type out the name of every dataframe. Each dataframe is named in a similar way: starts with "dma" then has the number of the dma it corresponds to (dma1-dma211). Is there a combine/merge function that allows me to select all dataframes that start with "dma" and combine them? All of the dataframes have the same columns and names of columns and I want to combine them vertically. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `mget` to get the values of the objects that starts with 'dma' followed by digits into a `list` and then `rbind` with `do.call` in `base R`

```
out <- do.call(rbind, mget(ls(patterns = '^dma\\d+$')))
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
out <- mget(ls(patterns = '^dma\\d+$')) %>%
          bind_rows
```

Comment: This code did not exactly work, but thank you for letting me know about the ls() function. that ended up being the piece I needed to make this all work, so I very much appreciate that!!!!

Comment: @Emily can you show what changes you made in the code.  thanks.  When there is no examples, it is a bit hard to understand the exact problem.